# What do "Enable Load" and "Include In Report Refresh" mean/do?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In Power Query, when I right-click on the name of a query (in the left-most pane of Power Query's window) I see selections for "Enable Load" and "Include In Report Refresh."

I cannot find an explanation of what these two selections actually mean and do. I'd definitely appreciate a brief tutorial.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"Include In Report Refresh" means query is automatically refreshed when you press "Refresh" button on the ribbon.

"Enable Load" means query results are available for report builder. Otherwise you may use it in your other queries (for example to merge data), but it is not shown in the report builder.

Comment: Both options make it seem like all covered, until you use Power BI service, ie PowerBI.com portal for publishing, then you find out neither actually stop the source data refreshes, causing failures or need for on-prem Gateway (likely to only fail later when source moves). 

You can use Azure SQL DB for cloud source instead, and/or vote for fix at 
https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/20579641-exclude-a-table-from-refresh-in-power-bi-service

Comment: @TickboxPhil When I wrote it back in 2017, it was working exactly like that. And take my excuses, but I don't quite understand what you have written there. Perhaps I am not too good in English.

Comment: I've not disputed your description as it still applies and answers the OP. Did you use it on PowerBI.com service (not local Desktop)? Having unticked "Include in Report Refresh" it doesn't do what it implies it does (ie stop refreshing the report!). It still tries to refresh, which causes errors, obviously because the source data is not local or available. It's an oversight and very frustrating, which is why 370 people have voted at that link - did you check that? I'm just raising this for others with this problem who come here wondering why it "works" strangely on the publish service.

Comment: @TickboxPhil, no, I didn't use PowerBI.com or online services yet. Should I do, I will note that thanks to your comment.
Thank you!

Comment: @TickboxPhil This is exactly the doubt I had in my mind and its crazy it works this way. Thank you for pointing this out !!

Comment: @Savvy MS just confirmed fix not on their ETA timeline yet, so please all, do vote (it's a bug not an "idea" really)!

Comment: As of today, Jan 2021, is there any change in the way this works in power BI desktop vs Power BI service?

Comment: As of today, Dec 2022, is there any change in the way this works in power BI desktop vs Power BI service?

Answer (score 0):

for Include In Report Refresh it is used to keep the old data, you will not extract the data from source, you can use it to be joined with other query, if it is old data and you don't keep fetch the data every time you make refresh

Answer (score 0):

Any queries excluded from refresh are also excluded in automatic refresh in the Power BI service.
[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-include-in-report-refresh)