# Power Bi - Load table from internet only once

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a Power BI report which I need to update one in a while.
All its tables were loaded from some internet URL, but only one of them needs to be updated, all the others have static data.

- How do I make Power BI stop trying to reload the static tables?
- Or how do I copy the data from these tables into new "non-internet-loaded" tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Query Editor, right-click on the queries and toggle off `Include in report refresh` where appropriate.

[image]

(The `Enable load` toggle is useful for queries that you only use for staging and don't actually want to load into your model.)

Comment: In Power BI desktop this is right answer. However when report is uploaded to Power BI service, then it doesn't work as per comments in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42073034/1779091