# How to prevent power query from fetching data for merge source tables?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

In Power query I have table A and table B.

I have merged these to create table C and expanded to keep the column I need in my report.

When I refresh the data, it fetches data from the source database into all 3 tables.

It doesn't allow me to delete tables A and B because they are used by the merge table C.

I have tried both unchecking enable load on the tables A and B as well as unchecking include in report refresh. As mentioned here (see comment section on answer - [What do "Enable Load" and "Include In Report Refresh" mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070677/what-do-enable-load-and-include-in-report-refresh-mean-do)), these options are effective only in power bi desktop and have no effect in power bi service.

So how can I prevent power query from fetching data for merge tables A and B so that it queries the source database only for table C?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. If C depends on A and B (and no other sources), how can it possibly be refreshed without refreshing at least one of A or B?

Comment: C is achieved after performing a merge on A and B. Hence C will have its own independent query steps.

Comment: It will have independent steps but these are just transformations on data that comes from the other queries. So if you only refresh those steps, nothing would change (assuming these steps are deterministic).